# How to let the user know that pages can be turned when using UIPageViewController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, user-interface, uipageviewcontroller

I just implemented a view in my iPhone app using UIPageViewController. The page turning looks really spiffy. But how do I let the user know that the page can or needs to be turned to get more content? I couldn't find anything in the reference manual.

One other wrinkle is some of my pages are larger than a single screen, so users are already scrolling up and down to get at more content. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to show the user that something can be moved is for the programmer to move it when it first appears.  For instance, if a have something that's a table but doesn't look like one, I scroll it to the end before I display it, then display it and scroll it back to the top as soon as it appears.  This has two effects:  1) your app looks slicker because there's some animation going on - the eye is attracted to movement 2) the user can see that there's more there because they watch it all scroll by.

So I'd recommend turning to the second page at startup and turning back programmatically when it first appears.  The user sees your clever animation right away without having to stumble on it himself, and he knows it can work that way.

Comment: I like this idea, but I'm not sure how to implement it in iOS. To the extent that I understand things, views and view controllers are loaded afresh each time they are visited. It seems like overkill to do this animation every time.

Comment: You only have to do it the first time the view is loaded. You just have to show the user once. Set a boolean in your appDelegate the first time it happens, then check if its set on following view loads.

Comment: If scrolling to the top is too fancy or if the table is just to big for this, them you might cosider to let the scroll indicators flash, which is a built in mechanism of the UIScrollView, from which the UITableView inherits: `[myTableView flashScrollIndicators]`

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely serious, but food for thought:

[image: A graphic with details instructions on how to use a print magazine.]

Source: [Khoi Vinh](http://www.subtraction.com/2011/03/28/an-illustration-for-stack-america)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Owen Hartnett seems to be the right one, which is why I marked it as the best. However, I'm still climbing up the steep iOS learning curve and I didn't want to take on learning how to create animations as well. So here is the solution/hack that I came up with.

I created a "cover" or first page for the view. I built and loaded the app into the simulator. I used my mouse to turn up the bottom right corner and took a screen shot. I then cropped the screen shot and added that image to the cover page that I created. I had to fiddle a little bit, because the gesture recognizer didn't seem to like having the entire screen be a PNG file. When I made the image a bit smaller, it worked.

Comment: Don't be afraid of Core Animation.  Often, you can do some pretty spectacular changes with only 4 or 5 lines of code.

Comment: I'll take this on in the new year on my next project. Today, I am doing battle with the provisioning certificate gods.